# NOP Gadget in Return Oriented Programming exploit technique

Tags: security, exploit

What exactly is NOP gadget in ROP - security exploit technique in Return Oriented Programming? I am reading some theory about ROP and there is only written that it is a pointer to the opcode C3 ret?

NOP means no operation for processor and when instruction pointer comes to it processor actually does not do anything, but one clock period expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOP's used in exploitation are normally used for memory alignment or creating nop sleds. These are just portions of memory that in effect do nothing (no operation) so things can go smoother. In the case of nop gadgets, they are exclusively used for aligning memory as far as I know, so that EIP doesn't read from the middle of a pointer, for example. In terms of crafting a payload or executing shellcode, they are used mostly when exact memory address aren't known or to align the shellcode correctly.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by middle of a pointer? You can read piece of a pointer or what and for what is that useful?